# defaultChecked and checked radio button are not working in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, radio-button

I made a screen to update already existing values in a form. In this form I want to show the input values of the gender in a radio button. The problem is that when I use checked I can't click the other radiobutton anymore and when I use defaultChecked none of them is highlighted.
[With checked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXk1K.png)
[With defaultChecked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lc1C8.png)

This is my code:

```
const [gender, setGender] = useState(0);

<div className="radio-buttons">
    <input
        type="radio"
        id="women"
        value={2}
        name="gender"
        checked={userItem.gender === 2}
        onChange={(e) => setGender(2)}
    />
    <label htmlFor="women">Women</label>

    <input
        type="radio"
        id="man"
        value={1}
        name="gender"
        checked={userItem.gender === 1}
        onChange={(e) => setGender(1)}
    />
    <label htmlFor="man">Man</label>
</div>
```

The `setGender()` useState works and the `userItem.gender === 1 or 2` also returns true or false.

I want that the received data is displayed in the radiobutton and that it is possible to change to the other radiobutton.

Comment: Works fine, but you have to actually use the state and not `userItem.gender` https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-sea-efzoz7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you are setting the checked value by using `userItem` and in `onChange` you are using `gender` variable.

An approach would be to set the gender value in `useEffect` if you are receiving the value as prop or from an api call.

Modified code would be:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [gender, setGender] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    //if you are recieving data from props or api,
    // set the gender value based on the recieved prop or data here
    // if(props.gender) {
    // setGender(props.gender);
    //}
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="radio-buttons">
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="women"
        value={2}
        name="gender"
        checked={gender === 2}
        onChange={(e) => setGender(2)}
      />
      <label htmlFor="women">Women</label>

      <input
        type="radio"
        id="man"
        value={1}
        name="gender"
        checked={gender === 1}
        onChange={(e) => setGender(1)}
      />
      <label htmlFor="man">Man</label>
    </div>
  );
}
```